# R - how to combine dataframes without duplicates

Tags: r

I have several dataframes in R that I need to combine. Normaly I would simply use left_join() function but this way I will get id and ord columns “duplicated”, there is just one id 1 in a dataframe thus it should be even in final dataframe only once too.

Here is my dataframes:

```
a <-
data.frame(id = seq(1, 2))

b <-
data.frame(
id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
ord = seq(1, 4)
)

c <-
data.frame(
id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
mar = seq(1, 8)
)
```

Here is desired result

```
result <-
data.frame(
id = c(1, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 2, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
ord = c(1, 2, NA_real_, NA_real_, 3, 4, NA_real_, NA_real_),
mar = seq(1, 8)
)
```

Please keep in mind that in the reality I have way more than just 3 dataframes.

Comment: `transform(c, id = id * NA^is.na(pmatch(id, pmatch(b$id, a$id))))`??

Comment: When the id appears in multiple rows, how do we decide which to replace with NAs?

Comment: Does this work for more columns, `bind_rows(a, b, c) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(everything(),  ~ .[order(is.na(.))]), .groups = 'drop') %>% filter(if_any(-id, complete.cases)) %>% mutate(id = replace(id, duplicated(id), NA))`